# where should I reset query after using get_results?

Tags: query, plugin-gravity-forms

I have the following code to populate checkbox fields in a gravity form. 
I have an array of field_ids I'm looping through with a foreach loop.
`$arr = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);`
I then have a second foreach loop with a query which is pulling data from the database.

The code is working however, each subsequent field_id is showing the results for that field_id AND the previous ones. 
eg field_id=6 is showing a list of checkbox fields for field_id=5 and field_id=6.
field_id= 7 is showing a list of checkbox fields for field_id=5, field_id=6 and field_id=7 etc.

```
function populate_checkboxes( $form ){

foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field )  {
    $arr = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    foreach($arr as $field_id){
      global $wpdb;
      $query = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT sefer FROM bulk_import where field_id_select_items = {$field_id}" );
      foreach($query as $sefer){

        if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {continue;}
        $choices[] = array( 'text' => 'Select All', 'value' => 'Select_all' ); 
        $inputs[] = array( 'label' => 'Select All', 'id' => '1'); 
        //get all $sefer values
        $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'=> array('learning_item'),   'suppress_filters' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'asc', 
        'meta_query' => array(  
            array( 'key' => 'taken',   'value' => '0'),
            array('key' => 'torah', 'value' => $sefer -> sefer)
        ),
        ));

        $input_id = 2;
        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            //skipping index that are multiples of 10 (multiples of 10 create problems as the input IDs)
            if ( $input_id % 10 == 0 ) {$input_id++;}
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
            $inputs[] = array( 'label' => $post->post_title, 'id' => "{$field_id}.{$input_id}" );

            $input_id++;
        }

        $field->choices = $choices; 
        $field->inputs = $inputs; 

      }
        //reset query here? 
         wp_reset_query();
    }

}
return $form;}
```

Do I need to reset the query somewhere? I tried to add wp_reset_query(); in a few different places but it didn't work. Where do I need to reset the query?

Comment: `wp_reset_query()` restores the `$wp_query` and global post data to the original main query. In the code snippet provided, you did not touch `$wp_query` or the main query. Thus, you don't need to reset your query. Your issue is elsewhere, but I can't pinpoint it. It read to me like a variable was not cleared (set to empty) before reusing it in the loop again, that would cause the carrying over of previous-data.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  adding foreach($query as $sefer){ $choices = array(); $inputs = array(); fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

adding the following fixed the issue

```
 foreach($query as $sefer){
                $choices = array();
                $inputs = array();
```